# В каждой строке поменять местами элемент главной диагонали строки с последним отрицательным элементом строки - C#

Tags: c#, for

В каждой строке поменять местами элемент главной диагонали строки с последним отрицательным элементом строки! Долго пытался, но всё напрасно. Помогите, буду очень благодарен!

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
        {
            mass2[i, j] = rand.Next(-20, 20);
            if (txtMass2.Text.Length == 0)
            {
                txtMass2.Text = "" + mass2[i, j];
            }
            else
                txtMass2.Text = txtMass2.Text + "\t" + mass2[i, j];
        }
        txtMass2.Text = txtMass2.Text + "\n";
        btnGenMass2.Enabled = false;
    }
    int temp=0;
    int temp1 = 0, a = 0, b = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        a = 0;
        b = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
        {
            if (mass2[0, j] < 0)
            {
                temp = mass2[0, j];
                a = i;
                b = j;
            }
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
        {
            if (i==j)
            {
               temp1 = mass2[i, j];
               mass2[i,j]=temp;
               mass2[a, b] = temp1;
            }
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
        {
            if (txtMass2.Text.Length == 0)
            {
                txtResMass2.Text = "" + mass2[i, j];
            }
            else
                txtResMass2.Text = txtMass2.Text + "\t" + mass2[i, j];
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// initialize matrix values
// ...

// in each row, swap last negative and main diagonal values:
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
  for (int j = 4; j >= 0; j--)
  {
    if (mass2[i, j] < 0)
    {
      temp = mass2[i, j];
      mass2[i, j] = mass2[i, i];
      mass2[i, i] = temp;
      break;
    }
  }
}

// output matrix values
// ...
```

Comment: Ничего не поменялось, может я что-то не так делаю?

Comment: @Alex Вы неаккуратно скопировали к себе мой код. Код отличный, не сомневайтесь :).

Comment: Спасибо огромное!

Comment: @Alex На здоровье. Успехов! Слева от ответа - значок "галочка".